# building in flex builder for flash player 10

Tags: flash, papervision3d

Is it possible to build Flash player 10 stuff, specifically papervision in Flex Builder latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just get the [latest version of the SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3).

I found some [instructions for setting up the FP10 preview](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/05/20/using-flash-player-10-within-flex-builder/), should be pretty similar for the full version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, just add this when compiling:

-target-player 10

You also need lastest Flex SDK as noted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got something wrong. Papervision3D is not Flash Player 10 exclusive. You can run  Papervision3D with Flash Player 9. So you don't have to go through that hassle. Escpecially since only a minority of people have FP 10 installed yet.

Comment: I'm not so concerned about install base. I just want to play with the bleeding edge.

Comment: FP 10 has a native Z-Axis now, but PaperVision3D does not need that.

Comment: where on earth did you get the idea only a minority of people have FP10? .. check http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html

Answer (score 0):

Pepervision3D currently does NOT take advantage of FP10's non-affine transform capability and still slices and dices quads into triangles. Meaning it works just fine for both FP9 and FP10. .. PapervisionX will appear some day and improve on this